Can we safely use react-router's private methods?
I want to access the navigate function outside of React, I read this question and got the following answer, it works, but I found that in the comment of this function it says: @internal PRIVATE - DO NOT USE, can I use this function safely? Thanks!
const router = createBrowserRouter([]);

router.navigate("/"); // is this safe?


"Safe" has no objective meaning here. No, you should not use it. Yes, it's safe if you never upgrade to a newer version. The file won't magically change underneath you, but if you ever intend to upgrade, or you are forced to upgrade because of a security issue, you may find your the private "DO NOT USE" methods have changed or vanished entirely. You have to decide for yourself whether you want to assume that risk.

It seems that only the navigate function that takes a delta number type is marked as being internal.
See router.ts source:

/**
 * @internal
 * PRIVATE - DO NOT USE
 *
 * Navigate forward/backward in the history stack
 * @param to Delta to move in the history stack
 */
navigate(to: number): Promise<void>;

/**
 * Navigate to the given path
 * @param to Path to navigate to
 * @param opts Navigation options (method, submission, etc.)
 */
navigate(to: To | null, opts?: RouterNavigateOptions): Promise<void>;


Though I suspect this is actually an oversight that the maintainers meant for both variants to be explicitly marked internal.

@internal PRIVATE - DO NOT USE, can I use this function safely?

React-Router/React-Router-DOM has a long history of surfacing "internal" functions/functionality/etc, usually accompanied by a comment similar to the following:
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// DANGER! PLEASE READ ME!
// We provide these exports as an escape hatch in the event that you need any
// routing data that we don't provide an explicit API for. With that said, we
// want to cover your use case if we can, so if you feel the need to use these
// we want to hear from you. Let us know what you're building and we'll do our
// best to make sure we can support you!
//
// We consider these exports an implementation detail and do not guarantee
// against any breaking changes, regardless of the semver release. Use with
// extreme caution and only if you understand the consequences. Godspeed.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

In other words, they don't officially support it, but still try to be helpful. The "unofficial" exports are completely safe to use until they are no longer safe to use, i.e. the maintainers finally decided to remove it from the library.
Regarding router.navigate(...), it was the official suggestion as of Nov 2, 2022, and is still the recommended method as of Mar 28, 2023 and no change in stance through the end of the Github issue thread.
